# Create global variable in utils.js file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm currently trying to figure it out how to properly define global variable in node.js. I know it is not a good practice to do this, but in this particular screnario it's the only way to do this without using connection to database.

I'm getting data from github API to display some information, I'm trying to store them in the global variable. It should allow me to e.g pass specific object from first global list to new global list that display only chosen items.

I have file called utils.js that have this two empty arrays that should be global:

```
let repoItems = [];
let bookmarkedItems = [];

exports.repoItems = repoItems;
exports.bookmarkedItems = bookmarkedItems;
```

Then I have another file that fetch and should assign items to the first global variable, but it looks like it doesn't. Because in the moment I'm trying to chose one item & push it into second empty array it's impossible, I'm getting empty array. I'm not sure if the mistake is taken because of bad implementation of global variable from other file, or something else :/

Below I include the fetching part of code, with bold part that I'm confused with:

```
let utils = require('../utils');

let {
    repoItems,
} = utils;

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await fetchGithubAPI(`searching word`);
        const urls = result.map(url => url);
        console.log(urls);
        res.render('repositories.ejs', {
            'data': urls
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

async function fetchGithubAPI(search) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/?q=${search}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    **repoItems = data.items.map(item => item);**
    return repoItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`let repoItems = require('./utils').repoItems`

instead of

```
let {
    repoItems,
} = utils;
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, still getting empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

if you remove

```
let {
repoItems,
```

} = utils;

you can try using 
utils.repoItems = data.items.map(item => item)

I tried an example setup for it

--utils.js

module.exports.someValue = 3;
module.exports.setSomeValue = (value) => {someValue = value}

--index.js

```
const utils = require('./utils'); 

console.log(utils.someValue);// 3
utils.someValue = 5
console.log(utils.someValue);// 5
```

Update after knowing about getter and setter methods in Js 
You can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set
this is another way to change value of any private properties in JS